# How to LEFT JOIN two tables with the same column name

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to LEFT JOIN two tables with the same column name.  I have two tables which I am trying to join but I keep getting an error:

```
column 'id' is ambiguous
```

returned in my JSON output.

My current query:

```
$sQuery = "
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
 FROM   $sTable
 LEFT JOIN
    $sTable2
    ON ($sTable2.id = $sTable.id)

 $sWhere
 $sOrder
 $sLimit
";
```

Produces that error.  How can I join these two tables as the join point when there is the same column name in each table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Be explicit about which table the column belongs to. This also applies to the SELECT part of the query:

```
SELECT table1.column AS column1, table2.column AS column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column = table2.column
```

To save you some typing time, use table aliases:

```
SELECT t1.column AS column1, t2.column AS column2
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.column = t2.column
```

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity is probably in the select, not in the join. The join looks OK. $aColumns probably contains "id" without table name specification or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), 
even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).
```

In your case, both table1 and table 2 are same. So There might be no benefit of doing Left Join because ultimately all the rows will be returned. You might wanna use Inner Join.