# MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to LEFT JOIN two tables with the same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119515/how-to-left-join-two-tables-with-the-same-column-name)

I have this statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM deliveries AS del 
        LEFT JOIN job_sheet ON job_sheet.job_id=del.jID
        LEFT JOIN hierarchy AS h ON job_sheet.h_str=h.hID
        LEFT JOIN customers ON h.cust=customers.ID";
```

My problem is that the 'customers' table has a column called ID and so does the 'deliveries' table. The issue starts when I run a while loop to output results.

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
     echo $data['ID'];
}
```

it outputs the value of the last table that was joined... How can I separate the two? I mean, I need to be able to output 'ID' from both tables, but in the query, it's the last table that wins. Renaming the column is not an option...

Any inputs?

Comment: Never `SELECT *` in a join query. Always be explicit about the columns in the `SELECT` list, and assign aliases:  `SELECT h.ID as h_id, del.ID as del_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with some tweaking:

```
    SELECT 
       deliveries.*, 
       job_sheet.*,
       customers.ID as CUSTOMERID
       FROM deliveries 
          LEFT JOIN job_sheet ON job_sheet.job_id=deliveries.jID 
          LEFT JOIN hierarchy ON job_sheet.h_str=hierarchy.hID 
          LEFT JOIN customers ON hierarchy.cust=customers.ID
```

Given that the only thing I needed from the customers table was an aliased 'ID' while keeping every other column from the other two tables.

My while loop would ultimately change to:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $data['CUSTOMERID']; // For the customer's ID
    echo $data['ID']; // For the delivery ID
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to explicitly call out the columns rather than using `*` and alias the columns with the same names in your query:

```
SELECT 
   del.ID as delivery_id,
   customers.ID as customer_id,
   .....
FROM deliveries AS del 
LEFT JOIN job_sheet ON job_sheet.job_id=del.jID 
LEFT JOIN hierarchy AS h ON job_sheet.h_str=h.hID 
LEFT JOIN customers ON h.cust=customers.ID
```

Comment: So far, I tried this out and it works nicely. My next question is, what if you need all 30 columns from that table. Would you have to write out every single one of them?

Comment: @Dimitri - best practice would be yes, list out all 30.  Alternatively you could just list out the ones you need to be aliased the follow that up with a `*`.  This would cause some columns to be selected more than once (maybe not a big deal)

Comment: Thanks! I used your example with a bit of tweaking and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the columns you want.  Personally, I don't have such a big problem with "*" in a select list, so long as it is aliased.  Something like:

```
select del.*, job_sheet.col1, . . .
```