# How can I avoid overwritten attributes when joining tables with Peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

When I use Peewee to join two tables and select attributes from both which have the same name, the last one overwrites any others. For example, with the following tables:

```
 from peewee import *

 db = SqliteDatabase(":memory:")

 class BaseModel(Model):
      class Meta:
           database = db

 class Module(BaseModel):
      name = CharField()

 class Student(BaseModel):
      name = CharField()
      member = ForeignKeyField(Module, related_name="members", null=True)

 db.create_tables([Module, Student], safe=True)
```

And data like this:

```
 history_id = Module.create(name="History")
 science_id = Module.create(name="Science")

 Student.create(name="Tim", member=history_id)
 Student.create(name="Mike", member=science_id)
```

And a Select like this:

```
 modules = Module.select(
      Student.name,
      Module.name
 ).join(
      Student,
      on=(Module.id == Student.member)
 ).group_by(Module).dicts()
```

I get:

```
 {'name': 'History'}
 {'name': 'Science'}
```

Or this, if I reverse the order in the Select:

```
 {'name': 'Tim'}
 {'name': 'Mike'}
```

Does Peewee provide a way to work around this?

Comment: This is probably a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048298/avoiding-conflicting-column-titles-in-table-join-in-peewee?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Just realised that Peewee's `alias()` can be [used on columns](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ColumnBase.alias) as well as tables:

```
 modules = Module.select(
      Module.name.alias("module_name"),
      Student.name.alias("student_name")
 ).join(
      Student,
      on=(Module.id == Student.member)
 ).group_by(Module).dicts()
```

Gives:

```
 SELECT "t1"."name" AS module_name, "t2"."name" AS student_name FROM "module" AS t1 INNER JOIN "student" AS t2 ON ("t1"."id" = "t2"."member_id") GROUP BY "t1"."id", "t1"."name"
```

And:

```
 {'module_name': 'History', 'student_name': 'Tim'}
 {'module_name': 'Science', 'student_name': 'Mike'}
```